# Why is my web application rendering differently on the same devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, user-interface

I have come across a very interesting UI issue with my web application.

When I open my web application on my phone (iPhone 7 Plus) or on my laptop (13' Macbook pro), everything looks perfect. However, when I open my web application on my buddies phone (iPhone 7 Plus) or on my buddies laptop (13' Macbook pro), everything looks distorted. I am so confused because we have the exact same devices with the exact same resolution sizes.

During testing/troubleshooting the issue, I used many friends/colleagues devices.

- Example.) I would open the web app on my friend's iPhone 5 and it would be distorted. Then I would open the web app on my other friend's iPhone 5 and it would be perfect.

I tested the example above with a lot more devices and the result was almost always the same.

I am currently using the Metronic default theme v5.05.

Thank you for all/any help provided!

Comment: For clarification: When I say it looks distorted on 50% of devices, what I mean is that some of the html components are pushed up or not where they should be.

Comment: Could be due to different default user settings like font-size for example. Use a css normalizer file so all devices and browsers have same defaults

Comment: [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) is helpful for this, much of what @charlietfl mentioned.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Apple products, but sounds like you may have a setting on your devices that your buddies do not. Do you have any example code/CSS that might help? This question would benefit by posting settings/configurations.

Comment: Normilize.css did not work and all of our device settings are the same :(